# Encoding error, in python3

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding, serial-port, pyserial

I have a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175928/erratic-encoding-of-byte-to-string-on-python-3-on-ubuntu/44176033?noredirect=1#comment75369342_44176033) that I can't solve. In another instance of my code, I face similar encoding errors. Do assist!

My code:

```
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600, timeout=10,     bytesize=8)
f_w = open('/home/ryan/python_serial_output.txt','r+')
f_o = open('/home/ryan/python_serial_parse.txt','w')

port.send_break()
sys_reply = port.read(100000)
sys_reply_str = sys_reply.decode('utf-8')
print(sys_reply_str)
sys_reply_str_haha = sys_reply_str.replace("\r","")
sys_reply_str_haha = sys_reply_str_haha.replace("\n","")
i = list(sys_reply_str_haha)
if str(i[-1]) == '>':
    ip = 'CR1'
    ip_en = ip.encode('utf-8')
    port.write(ip_en)
    read_syscheck = port.read(100000)
    read_syscheck_str = read_syscheck.decode('utf-8')
    print(read_syscheck_str)
```

Yes, it's inefficient, but I'm writing it step by step to avoid errors as a start.

With this code, this is the result I get.

```
myname@Toshiba:~$ python3 serial_test.py 

Explorer (c) 2009
All rights reserved.
Firmware Version: 34.11  

>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    read_syscheck_str = read_syscheck.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 7: invalid continuation byte
```

It seems I am encoding 'CR1' wrongly, that's why the error has been prompted. CR1 is supposed to reset my sensor to factory default settings, and meant to reply a confirmation of that.

Thank you very much in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `print(read_syscheck)` after reading the port yield?

Comment: it has the same result as print(read_syscheck_str)

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't thinking straight earlier and did not comment out the decoding line, hence it hit an error.

this is the reply from print(read_syscheck_str):
b'CR1\r\n\x7f\x7f\xd3\x00\x00\x03\x0c\x82\x00\x00........

I'm on linux so using GTKTerm to talk to the sensor as a guide. This is the output I am expecting. 

....
All rights reserved.
Firmware Version: 34.11

>CR1
[Parameters set to FACTORY defaults]

>

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow. @AetherUnbound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong encoding method.

Correct one was 'cp437'

Unsure why UTF-8 worked after the break, but not after writing a command